# elastic4s hitreader throw error value to is not a member of Either[..]

Tags: scala, elastic4s

I wrote this sample

`val characters :Seq[Character] = resp.to[Character]`

for convert JSON to object but throw below error

> value to is not a member of
>   Either[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.RequestFailure,com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.RequestSuccess[MyObject]]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`resp` is an `Either` so you must match on that to extract the RequestSuccess from the right case.

```
resp match {
  case Left(failure) => // do something
  case Right(success) => success.to[Character]
}
```